# What is a word or phrase meaning "to bring in account" or "to bring into a controlled state"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, phrase-requests

What is a word or phrase meaning "to bring in account" or "to bring into a controlled state"?

I don't think "to bring into account" is exactly the phrase I'm looking for...
I want to convey the idea of taking something which is in an unknown state and beginning to manage or know the state. I don't want to imply *only* discovery  or management of the state, but both.

For example: "The software developers finally _____ their messy project by setting up a version control system." (the example sentence can be re-worked to fit the phrase if necessary)

Thanks!

Comment: For your future use "bring in account" does not mean "bring into a controlled state", or anything like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [*rein in*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rein%20in):

**to limit or control** (someone or something):
 *Congress must rein in spending*. *You had better rein that kid in before she gets hurt*.

*The software developers finally reined in their messy project by setting up a version control system.*

Comment: Equestrian idioms seem apt here.  *Tamed*.  *Corralled*.